# Lamda to process SQS messages not triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function that's supposed to process my SQS messages.  However, it doesn't seem to be triggered automatically even though I have my SQS as its event trigger.  Below is my code.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    max=2 # Number of messages to process @ a time
    if "max" in event:
        max=int(event["max"])
    else:
        max=1
    sqs = boto3.resource('sqs') # Get access to resource
    queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='mysqs.fifo') # Get queue by name
    count=0
    # Process messages
    for message in queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=max):
        body = json.loads(message.body) # Attribute list
        print("test")
        payload = message[body]
        print(str(payload))
        count+=1
        message.delete()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': str(count)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When an AWS Lambda function is configured with Amazon SQS as a trigger, the messages are passed in via the `event` variable. The code inside the function should **not** call Amazon SQS directly.

Here is an example of an `event` being passed to the function:

```json
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
            "body": "Test message.",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
                "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
                "MessageGroupId": "1",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
                "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your code could then access the messages with:

```py
for record in event['Records']:
    payload = record['body']
    print(payload)
    count += 1
```

There is no need to delete the message -- it will be automatically deleted once the Lambda function successfully executes.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

Comment: Best practice is to delete the messages yourself. This avoids batch retries when one message causes an error.